# IE11-10 contenteditable mouse events not getting fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When we make a element content editable and we do mousedown in that element then mousedown and mousemove(when moved) of that element is fired. But if we move our mouse to other element(keeping button pressed) then mouseove of other elements are not fired.

Check jsFiddle at "http://jsfiddle.net/yvB77/"

In this do mousedown at editable element and then move mouse to non-editable element and check that text in 3rd p is not updated as mousemove of other element is not fired.

```
<p class="editable" contenteditable="true">Hello I am editable</p>
<p class="non-editable"> I am non-editable</p>

<p class="text"></p>


var ismousedown=false;
$('p').mousedown(function(e){
    ismousedown=true;
});
$('p').mousemove(function(e){
    if(ismousedown){ 
        $('.text').html($(this).html());
    }
});
$('p').mouseup(function(e){
    ismousedown=false;

});
```

I have added the question on Microsoft IE forum and they are able to replicate the bug but no fix or workaround has been suggested
"https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/834296/content-editable-and-mouseevents"

Comment: In your jsfiddle, I'm moving to 'Editable' element, click-and-hold left mouse button, and am moving to 'non-editable' element. The behavior is... when the mouse is on 'Editable' the third para shows editable ele text. When the mouse is moved on top of non-editable element, the third para shows non-editable ele text... Isn't that the behavior you are expecting ? How do you want it to behave ?

Comment: Yes but the same is not happening in IE In Ie when I press and hold the mouse button on editable and move to non-editable, third paragraph text is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Known limitation

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/834296/content-editable-and-mouseevents

Not able to find any fix or workadound for this